# regex in java that takes text and numbers between superscripts when the second superscript is before a round or square bracket or a comma

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex in java that takes the text between superscripts when the second superscript is before a round or square bracket or a comma

This is my attempt but it doesn't work

```
'([^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*)
```

This is the test string

> `( $REC_REM$.cApplicationOrigin == '---' )  ||  ( $REC_REM$.cApplicationOrigin in ['AOL MOBILE','FASTWEB','POS.TE','SALES'FORCE','13'] )`

I would like to get as results

```
---
AOL
MOBILE
FASTWEB
POS.TE
SALES'FORCE
13
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex in Java and grab capture group #1 for your matches:

```bash
'(.+?)'\h*[,)\]]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nuSdxc/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `'`: Match opening `'`
- `(.+?)`: Match 1+ of any characters (lazy match)
- `'`: Match closing `'`
- `\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `[,)\]]`: Match comma or `)` or `]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I wanted to catch the '---'  how can I change it?

Comment: It is a file provided by a third-party software. I need to capture only the text between superscripts when the second superscript is before a closing round bracket, closing bracket, or a comma.

Comment: ok can you clarify with examples like what is `text between superscripts` in this example text and what is `second superscript`?

Comment: Because I want to capture words or any character that have superscripts in them. In the example written above I want capture 'SALES'FORCE' not 'SALES'. And I want '---' or for example '+++' to be caught too. I hope I have explained myself.

Comment: ok try my updated answer now

Comment: Ok perfect. I put as correct answer. Only one question happened to me during a test that the file ends with 'string' because of rolling of file and this is not captured. Can it be managed?

Comment: You can try: `'(.+?)'\h*(?:[,)\]]|\z)`